# Ajax request never succeeds but no error

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, ajax

I'm trying to load a dropdown list from an ajax call. Here's my code:

```
<select name="customer" onChange="testAJAX(this.value)">
    <option value="0" selected >Select Customer</option>
    <?php
        $services = db_query('SELECT cust_id,cust_name FROM '.CUST_TABLE.' ORDER BY cust_name');

        while (list($cust_id,$name) = db_fetch_row($services)){
            $selected =($info['customer']==$cust_id)?'SELECTED':'';?>
                <option value="<?=$cust_id?>"<?=$selected?>><?=$name?></option>
                    <?php
                     }?>
</select>
```

Javascript function

```
function testAJAX(custID) {
$('#sLocation').empty();

var myURL = "getLocations.php?custID=" + custID;

$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: myURL,
    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: { custID : custID },
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(data){ 
        document.getElementById("sLocation").innerHTML = data; 
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            document.getElementById("sLocation").innerHTML = xhr.responseText; 
    },
    complete: function(){

    }
});
```

}

and the page it calls

```
<?php 

$custID = 0;
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "James", "mypassword", "OSTickets"); 

if (isset($_REQUEST['custID'])) {
    $custID = $_REQUEST['custID'];
}

$sql = 'SELECT l.location_id, l.site_name FROM ost_customer_location' 
. ' AS l JOIN ost_customer'
. ' AS c ON c.cust_id=l.cust_id'
. ' WHERE c.cust_id='.$custID;

$locations = array();

$str = "";
$str .= "<option value='0'>Select Location</option>";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
        $str .= "<option value=".$row["0"].">".$row["1"]."</option>";
    }
}
echo $str;
?>
```

I can get it to work but only in the error function of the ajax rather than the success but when I alert xhr.responseText, it doesn't show any error, just the select's html code which is:

```
<option value='0'>Select Location</option>
<option value='252'>Location 1</option>
<option value='345'>Location 2</option>
```

How do I figure out what error it's throwing?

Changed the error function to

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ console.log(jqXHR); }
```

and this is the response from the console.

Object {readyState: 4, responseText: " Duke Rd - Primary", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}

Comment: having both a complete() and success()/error() is redundant

Comment: Thanks, I eliminated the complete function, but I still get the problem

Comment: PHP error handling? Console errors? Does the PHP work on its own?

Comment: @godmode it's not. It's perfectly fine to have code that handles success, one that handles error, and one that runs regardless (say, to remove an icon indicating an ajax call is being made)

Comment: can you confirm with a simple console.log('here') that it's NOT getting to success or error? If you open google dev tools and go to the network tab you should be able to see the request and if it returned a 200/404/500

Comment: You've set 'contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",' but your php is returning a plain string. jQuery is probably trying to convert to JSON be is silently failing

Comment: @Andre, that's what `always()` is for

Comment: I keep the console up and it doesn't return anything. I do an alert('a') in the success function that I left out of the above code since it's just testing to see if it gets there and never does. Everything returned a 200 in the network tab. There are probably hundreds of php warnings and errors that come from the developers of this app so I rarely turn them on. I assumed if I got an error I could figure it out from alerting the response in the error function in ajax which would be easier than trying to sort through their error list.

Comment: @godmode from the jQuery docs , `always` is `An alternative construct to the complete callback option`. Only the `complete` method of `jqXHR` that was deprecated, the callback was not.

Comment: @Jeff So I would just change that to "application/json" and remove the charset part? I tried that, and removed the contentType completely and same response. No error, 200 HTTP response and still goes to the error function.

Comment: What is the responseText saying?

Comment: <option value='0'>Select Location</option>
<option value='252'>Location 1</option>
<option value='345'>Location 2</option>

Comment: You're not supplying valid html - you need the select element to wrap the options in.

Comment: I wrapped it in the select but still got to the error function.

Comment: I changed the error function in the code above to write to the console and the response is shown above.